# Diffusion of magnetization (NMR)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, diffusion

In the context of MRI I'm trying to understand the mechanisms of magnetization diffusion.

Consider a sample that is magnetized by an external magnetic field. We have displacement of magnetic moment carrying nuclei (or spins) due to Brownian motion. A diffusive flux of spin up/down nuclei (and magnetic moment) leads to a diffusive flux of magnetization ($\vec M$) by averaging/integration. With that reasoning, [Torrey (1956)](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.104.563)) extends the Bloch equation by a diffusion term $\nabla\cdot(D\nabla\vec M)$. That's how I picture diffusion. Correct?

On the other hand, in many refs they say that diffusion is **due** to inhomogeneities in the magnetic field---and that's where I get confused. This seems to be "general knowledge" and the starting point of discussions that lead to diffusion imaging: *create* an inhomogeneous field by adding a field gradient and `enable' diffusion of $M$, so you can measure $D$, which conveniently is (for example) the (effective) diffusion coefficient of water in the tissue.

- How do magnetic field inhomogeneities cause diffusion of the magnetization, $M$?
- A gradient is needed for spatially resolved imaging, but is there 'interaction' with the diffusion of magnetization? (And MRI was developed some decades later than the Torrey-Bloch-Eq.)

Maybe someone can clarify, I'm obviously confusing some things...